# Laravel Socialite - get user details by token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, laravel, laravel-5

I'am developing android application with facebook login and laravel REST API server. After user login on mobile, app get **token** which is sent to my server. On server I want get facebook user details by **token**.

*Facebook SDK* for PHP provides methods for that:

```
$session = new FacebookSession('token');
$me = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me',))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
```

Can [Laravel Socialite](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication) obtain user facebook details based on that **token**? Or just use that *Facebook SDK*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method [`getUserByToken`](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php#L73) implemented in the Facebook Service Provider, however it's `protected` and only used internally to get the [`user`](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/src/Two/AbstractProvider.php#L172) details.

So you're better off using the Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 17):

I submitted a pull request to the repo which was accepted to the 2.o branch.  You should be able to call `Socialte::driver('facebook')->userFromToken($token)` now.

https://github.com/laravel/socialite/pull/126

Cheers.

Comment: Just what I was after - shame there hasn't been a release yet this year to include it!

Comment: FYI make sure you are using a minimum of Socialite 2.0.15 which was released March 21 2016.

Comment: I've just updated to v2.0.15 and that method still seems to be protected.

Comment: If you get error like
Non-static method Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory::driver() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context.
Change this line:
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;
to:
use Socialite;
source: http://jakzaprogramowac.pl/pytanie/21154,unable-to-use-laravel-socialite-with-lumen

Answer (score 3):

You can also extend your Socialite Facebook Provider.
For example;
Create a class as SocialConnect in App/Library folder

```
namespace App\Library;

use Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider;

    class SocialConnect extends FacebookProvider {

        public function userFromToken($access_token)
        {
            $user = $this->mapUserToObject($this->getUserByToken($access_token));
            return $user->setToken($access_token);
        }
    }
```

Then add these lines in boot method on your App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
 $socialite = $this->app->make('Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory');
    $socialite->extend(
        'SocialConnect',
        function ($app) use ($socialite) {
            $config = $app['config']['services.facebook'];
            return $socialite->buildProvider(SocialConnect::class, $config);
        }
    );
```

Ready for use!

```
Socialite::driver('SocialConnect')->userFromToken($accessToken)
```

You can also add new methods as you wish in your SocialConnect class.