# How to get Facebook id using socialite laravel-5 using Face Book token

Tags: api, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am new in Laravel 5
I am creating API for Android app using Laravel 5
the other developer sent Facebook token in post method so
I have the Facebook token 
I need guidelines to using the token to get Facebook id any help will be appreciated (i don't using socialite)
Anyway thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Socialite - get user details by token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543991/laravel-socialite-get-user-details-by-token)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it any way

```
  $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        try {
            $res = $client->get('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,picture&access_token=' . $facebook_token);

        } catch (RequestException $e) {

            $status = 'Login Invalid';
            return \Response::json(['status' => $status, 'user' => '']);
        }
        $facebookUser = json_decode($res->getBody());

        $facebookId = $facebookUser->id;
        $facebookUsername = $facebookUser->name;
        $facebookUserPicture = $facebookUser->picture;
        $pictureURL = $facebookUserPicture->data->url;
```

hope that help any one